# How to appropriately choose entries from database when using ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm writing an application for a bike shop. I need to be able to assign many `Repairs` (i.e. a flat repair) to a `Transaction`. Each repair has a name, description, and price. Each transaction has a `repairs` field. For `Transaction`, I have

```
repairs = models.ManyToManyField(Repair, blank=True)
```

which makes logical sense. However, there will be some 40-odd different kinds of repairs. When I add repairs to a transaction, I don't want to have to create new instances of a `Repair` each time I create a new transaction and add repairs to it - I'd like to just have a pointer of sorts to that specific repair. **In other words, `Repair` acts as a list of possible repairs, with prices and descriptions, and `Transaction` has a field that points to a list of these repairs.** Additionally, my field in `Transaction` needs to be able to specify whether each repair has been completed.

I need to do the same kind of thing for `Item` (i.e., a tube) being pointed to by a `Transaction`.

I'm unsure how to do this in Django. I may be overthinking it, or my database design may be poor.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a reasonable design, and the inbuilt `ManyToManyField` is a good choice for that schema.

In terms of the user interface, if you're using the Django forms module to build forms and receive and validate the data, I would suggest that a `MultipleChoiceField` may be your best bet to select the `Repair` objects that are to be associated with the `Transaction`. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield). In that case, you can filter the available `Repair`s for the transaction in the form `__init__` method.